# AuthenticatedFailed error when pairing bluetooth mouse bluetoothctl

Tags: 16.04, mouse, bluetooth, bluez

I've been at this all day with no luck. I'm trying to pair my Logitech MX Master (bluetooth mouse) on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. The mouse shows up in gnome's bluetooth settings panel but trying to pair doesn't work at all, no error messages.

Using `bluetoothctl` I do:

```
scan on
agent on
<device appears>
scan off
pair <mac address>
Attempting to pair with <mac address>
[CHG] Device <mac address> Connected: yes
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
[CHG] Device <mac address> Connected: no
```

I'm at a loss here. I've tried everything under the sun from googling around. There doesn't seem to be much information regarding the `org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed` error message either. There is no prompt for a PIN code, just fails with those 3 messages in under a second.

I've tried setting `sspmode` on my bluetooth controller using `hciconfig` with no luck.

The most annoying thing is it was working over the last few days without a problem.